# TensorflowJS with earlyStopping and Training Logs does not work

Tags: tensorflow.js

TensorflowJS does not seem to work when we define early stopping and a training log function at the same time. The examples above is taken from the TensorflowJS docs, I just added the onTrainBegin callback -- but it fails.

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: 3,
  activation: 'softmax',
  kernelInitializer: 'ones',
  inputShape: [2]
}));
const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [2, 3]);
const xsVal = tf.tensor2d([4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 2]);
const ysVal = tf.tensor2d([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]], [2, 3]);
model.compile(
    {loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: 'sgd', metrics: ['acc']});

const onTrainBegin = function onTrainBegin(logs){
     console.log("onTrainBegin");
}


// Without the EarlyStopping callback, the val_acc value would be:
//   0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, ...
// With val_acc being monitored, training should stop after the 2nd epoch.
const history = await model.fit(xs, ys, {
  epochs: 10,
  validationData: [xsVal, ysVal],
  callbacks: [onTrainBegin, tf.callbacks.earlyStopping({monitor: 'val_acc'})]
});

// Expect to see a length-2 array.
console.log(history.history.val_acc);
```

This code yields the error message:

> An error occured this.getMonitorValue is not a function

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#callbacks.earlyStopping

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing different things. `OntrainBegin` specifies when the callback function is to be executed and  `tf.callbacks.earlyStopping({monitor: 'val_acc'})` is a function

```js
(async() => {
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  units: 3,
  activation: 'softmax',
  kernelInitializer: 'ones',
  inputShape: [2]
}));
const xs = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]], [2, 3]);
const xsVal = tf.tensor2d([4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 2]);
const ysVal = tf.tensor2d([[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]], [2, 3]);
model.compile(
    {loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: 'sgd', metrics: ['acc']});

const  onTrainBegin = logs => {
     console.log("onTrainBegin");
}


// Without the EarlyStopping callback, the val_acc value would be:
//   0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, ...
// With val_acc being monitored, training should stop after the 2nd epoch.
const history = await model.fit(xs, ys, {
  epochs: 10,
  validationData: [xsVal, ysVal],
  callbacks: [
   tf.callbacks.earlyStopping({monitor: 'val_acc'}), new tf.CustomCallback({
      onEpochEnd: onTrainBegin()}),
 ]
});

// Expect to see a length-2 array.
console.log(history.history.val_acc);
})()
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But early Stopping does not seem to be working on your example.

Comment: Thanks again, but not working still. The async function enclosing the example is suppressing an error message. If early stopping were to be working, it should stop after the 2º epoch. Moreover, it does not make sense to call the onTrainBegin() as it is in there. You can see it is not working if you try to add patience: 5 in the early stopping function.

Comment: Hey there! You have `monitor: 'val_acc'` here, but I can't seem to find any definitive docs on the different values it supports - even [the official docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#callbacks.earlyStopping) doesn't offer anything here.

Comment: `tf.CustomCallBack` is needed to create a `tf.callback` object with the `onEpochEnd` function. See my edited answer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @edkeveked. I see no edits to the answer, and no calls to `tf.CustomCallBack`, nor do I see `CustomCallBack` in the [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/)....

Comment: I forgot to edit the post. There is no mention of it in the docs yet. But you can have a look at the source code directly on github. Additionnaly here is a similar issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1792

Answer (score 1):

Below an example of the working code for using `earlyStopping` and `tf.CustomCallback` in model training in tfjs.

```
await model.fitDataset(convertedTrainingData, 
                         {epochs: 50,
                            validationData: convertedTestingData,
                          callbacks:[
                              new tf.CustomCallback({
                                onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                                    acc = logs.acc;
                                    console.log("Epoch: " + epoch 
                                              + " Loss: " + logs.loss.toFixed(4) 
                                              + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc.toFixed(4) 
                                              + " Val Loss: " + logs.val_loss.toFixed(4) 
                                              + " Val Accuracy: " + logs.val_acc.toFixed(4));
                                            },
                                onTrainEnd: async() =>{
                                    console.log("training done");
                                    if (acc>0.4) {
                                        repeat = false;
                                        console.log(repeat);
                                    }
                                }
                            }),
                            tf.callbacks.earlyStopping({monitor: 'loss'})
                        ]});
```